# Excel SUMIF when it validates that a cell range consists of a word or number (Statement of Accounts calculation)

Tags: excel

Excel sheet image click -> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pK77.png)

Hi people, currently I'm trying to make a Statement of Accounts using excel spreadsheet. I need help in creating the formula for the "??" highlighted in red as shown in the picture (Cells F17 and H17).

What i need it to be is that the cell in F17 searches for the strings in the Date column (B6 to B8) and then summing the cells in (E6 and E8) when it sees number "10" in the each of the date column (B6 to B8) as it is for month of October.

Please assist.
Here is the answer to the above https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726455/9075574

UPDATE:

Hey guys, currently im facing another error which returns a #VALUE in my cells as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrN3z.png) after 'beautifying' the template.

This is the code as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mitri.png).

Any idea why? I tried modifying the code to my needs but it seems like it created more problems. UPDATE: Problem solved and solution is posted below.

Comment: Do cells E17 and G17 contain a date?

Comment: Yes, it is technically a date, but its just written as a month because its a summary of all the $ amounts of the outstanding invoices

Comment: Working formulas for oktober and november 2017: `=SUMIFS(E6:E8,B6:B8,">=43009",B6:B8,"<43040")` and `=SUMIFS(E6:E8,B6:B8,">=43040",B6:B8,"<43070")` But of course, that is not maintainable.

Comment: @pnuts Yep. Should have been the dates `1 oct 2017`, `1 nov 2017` and `1 dec 2017` - But you cannot put them in the formulas ...  :(  Might still work if the "bottom of month" dates are somewhere on the sheet., Anyway, this does not depend on the format of the date column (as long as it contains dates, not  strings. (By the way: Your code did not work on my example sheet.) But your code *did* work on the sheet of the OP, and that's the most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Full solution Debit & Credit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX4Jb.png)

Ei guys, I've found the solution i need after trying the codes from @pnuts and @barryhoudini and modifying it to my needs (sorry if i got your name incorrectly). Most importantly, the Months summary(e.g Cell B35) must be in mmm/yy number formats for the code to work. Just would like to share it so hopefully it'll help people who needs it.